# How do I change state in reducer from a click in my component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I am working on a collaborative project, I wanted to know if I could change the state in my reducer by an onClick event listener or anything in my component.

```
const defaultState = {
  pending: false,
  error: null,
  trips: {},
  activeTrip: null,
  privacy: false
}
export const tripReducer = (state = defaultState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
case TOGGLE_VISIBILITY_ON:
      return {
        ...state,
        visibility: true,
      }
    case TOGGLE_VISIBILITY_OFF:
      return {
        ...state,
        visibility: false,
      }
}
```

These are the cases that I am concerned with atm. So I want to change visibility once a person marks their trip public in the activepanel component.

code for activePanel

```
import React from "react"
import * as s from "./components"
import { connect } from "react-redux"
import moment from "moment"
import PropTypes from "prop-types"
import { TripPropTypes } from "../../propTypes"
import { Button } from "../../../styles/theme/styledComponents"
import { toggleWaypoint } from "../../../redux/actions/trips"
import marker from "../../icons/orange-marker.svg"
import startMarker from "../../icons/green-marker.svg"
import endMarker from "../../icons/black-marker.svg"
import { Link } from "react-router-dom"

class ActiveTripPanel extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)

    this.state = {
      polylines: null,
      markers: []
    }
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.renderWaypoints()
      this.drawPolylines()
    }, 500)
  }

  componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
    if (prevProps.waypoints !== this.props.waypoints) {
      this.renderWaypoints()
      this.drawPolylines()
    }
  }

  drawPolylines = () => {
    if (this.state.polylines !== null) {
      this.state.polylines.active.setMap(null)
      this.state.polylines.complete.setMap(null)
      this.state.polylines.current.setMap(null)
    }

    let completeIndex = 0
    for (let i = 0; i < this.props.waypoints.length; i++) {
      if (!this.props.waypoints[i].complete) {
        completeIndex = i
        break
      }
    }

    const completed = this.props.waypoints.slice(0, completeIndex)
    const active = this.props.waypoints.slice(
      completeIndex,
      this.props.waypoints.length + 1
    )
    const current = this.props.waypoints.slice(
      completeIndex - 1,
      completeIndex + 2
    )
    const completePath = completed.map(waypoint => {
      return { lat: waypoint.lat, lng: waypoint.lon }
    })

    const activePath = active.map(waypoint => {
      return { lat: waypoint.lat, lng: waypoint.lon }
    })

    const currentPath = current.map(waypoint => {
      return { lat: waypoint.lat, lng: waypoint.lon }
    })
    const completePolyline = new window.google.maps.Polyline({
      path: completePath,
      strokeColor: "#FF0000",
      strokeOpacity: 1.0,
      strokeWeight: 2
    })

    const currentPolyline = new window.google.maps.Polyline({
      path: currentPath,
      strokeColor: "#008000",
      stokeOpacity: 1.0,
      stokeWeight: 2
    })
    const activePolyline = new window.google.maps.Polyline({
      path: activePath,
      strokeColor: "#000000",
      strokeOpacity: 1.0,
      strokeWeight: 2
    })

    completePolyline.setMap(window.map)
    activePolyline.setMap(window.map)
    currentPolyline.setMap(window.map)
    this.setState({
      polylines: {
        active: activePolyline,
        complete: completePolyline,
        current: currentPolyline
      }
    })
  }

  renderWaypoints = () => {
    let markers = []
    const baseIcon = {
      anchor: new window.google.maps.Point(15, 30),
      scaledSize: new window.google.maps.Size(30, 30),
      labelOrigin: new window.google.maps.Point(15, 13)
    }
    const icons = {
      start: {
        url: startMarker,
        ...baseIcon
      },
      end: {
        url: endMarker,
        ...baseIcon
      },
      marker: {
        url: marker,
        ...baseIcon
      }
    }
    this.props.waypoints.map((item, i) => {
      const icon =
        i === 0
          ? icons.start
          : i === this.props.waypoints.length - 1
          ? icons.end
          : icons.marker

      let center = { lat: item.lat, lng: item.lon }
      const marker = new window.google.maps.Marker({
        position: center,
        map: window.map,
        icon,
        title: item.name,
        label: {
          text: `${i + 1}`,
          color: "white",
          fontFamily: "Wals",
          fontWeight: "bold"
        }
      })
      markers.push(marker)
    })
  }

  render() {
    // console.log(match.params.tripId)
    // const publicId = ({ match })
    return (
      <s.Panel>
        {/* <s.PanelHeader>{this.props.trip.name}</s.PanelHeader>
        <s.DateLabel>
          Start: {moment(this.props.trip.start).format("YYYY-MM-DD")} - End:{" "}
          {moment(this.props.trip.end).format("YYYY-MM-DD")}
        </s.DateLabel> */}
        <Link to={`/public/${this.props.trip.id}`}>Share Trip</Link>
        <s.WaypointTracker>
          {this.props.waypoints &&
            this.props.waypoints.map(waypoint => (
              <s.WaypointStepper key={waypoint.id}>
                <div>
                  <h4>{waypoint.name}</h4>
                  <div>
                    ETA: {moment(waypoint.start).format("YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm")}
                  </div>
                  <div>
                    Status: Checked In @{" "}
                    {moment(waypoint.start).format("HH:mm")}
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div>
                  {waypoint.complete ? (
                    <Button
                      onClick={() => this.props.toggleWaypoint(waypoint.id)}
                    >
                      <i className="fa fa-check" />
                    </Button>
                  ) : (
                    <Button
                      onClick={() => this.props.toggleWaypoint(waypoint.id)}
                    >
                      <i className="fa fa-times" />
                    </Button>
                  )}
                </div>
              </s.WaypointStepper>
            ))}
        </s.WaypointTracker>
      </s.Panel>
    )
  }
}

ActiveTripPanel.propTypes = {
  trip: TripPropTypes,
  waypoints: PropTypes.array.isRequired,
  toggleWaypoint: PropTypes.func.isRequired
}

const mapStateToProps = ({ trips }) => ({
  trip: trips.activeTrip,
  waypoints: trips.activeTrip && trips.activeTrip.waypoints,
  visibility: trips.visibility
})

export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  { toggleWaypoint }
)(ActiveTripPanel)
```

I want to know if its possible or if theres another way to go about it. I am novice at redux. Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 0):

I read the question's text, not the code (long... :)
It is very common (probably the most common way) to change the reducer's state following an event (e.g. onClick):

- the onClick event calls an action creator
- The action creator returns an action
- The action is handled by the reducer
- The reducer changes the state.

Does this make sense? I am not sure I understand your question, since this is a standard flow in redux.

BTW, you might want to read an excellent article which helped me when I started learning redux: https://www.sohamkamani.com/blog/2017/03/31/react-redux-connect-explained/